# Cant find PasswordValidator property in UserManager, AspNet.Identity 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-3

I want to change the password requirements for my registration form but I cant find the PasswordValidator property in the UserManager class.

I'm using AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework 3.0.0-beta5

```
private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<AppUser> _signInManager;

        public AccountController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager)
        {

            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;

            // UserManager does not contain a definition for PasswordValidator
            //_userManager.PasswordValidator

        }
```

(For comparison, in Microsoft ASP.NET Identity 2.0, documentation for `UserManager<TUser, TKey>.PasswordValidator` is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151680%28v=vs.108%29.aspx#P:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager%602.PasswordValidator).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to fix it by changing the identity options in my startup.cs

This is what it looked like before

```
    services.AddIdentity<Models.Identity.AppUser, IdentityRole>()
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<test.Models.Identity.IdentityDataContext>();
```

This is what it looks like now

```
services.AddIdentity<Models.Identity.AppUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<test.Models.Identity.IdentityDataContext>();
```